# The DLL is partly missed in remote kernel debugging

Tags: windows, debugging, dll, windbg, ida

I'm doing some remote kernel debugging with IDA + WinDBG plugin and I want to set a breakpoint in some function inside the DLL, which I found while disassembling it in IDA. I switched to the process, which loads the target DLL, but unfortunately I found out that the DLL in memory is partly missed including my function.

Examples for proof are below. Here IDA recognized the function `sub_180001FC8`, but in WinDBG this disassembly breaks off on address `0x7fff3d131fff`.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7irEh.png) - DLL loaded into memory in live kernel debugging

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UebuR.png) - same DLL opened in IDA "statically"

What's wrong and how to recover missed parts?

Comment: check if the section is pageble or discardable most of the kernel mode drivers have sections  that are discardable

Comment: Try using .pagein <address> to load this page into memory in Windbg

Comment: @blabb, thank you! It appeared that memory page at this address was paged out

Comment: @oridamari, exactly what I needed! .pagein command did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.
The region where disassembly breaks off with `??` is paged out memory region.
To "restore" the page I used the command:

```
.pagein /f /p <process_address> <page_start_address>
```

For my situation:

```
.pagein /f /p 0xffffbc4a4405efc0 0x7fff3d132000
```

This command loads memory pages from secondary storage and they become visible in disassembly.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-pagein--page-in-memory-